# How to prevent someone from rapid clicking on a FileDownloader button in Vaadin 8?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

Using the code from the [Vaadin manual](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/articles/LettingTheUserDownloadAFile.html) we have:

```
Button downloadButton = new Button("Download image");
FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(createResource());
fileDownloader.extend(downloadButton);
```

The problem with this sample code is that someone could just start to rapid click on the `downloadButton` non-stop and the dynamically created file would be generated as quickly as the user can click. Is there a way to put a limiter, that is say after x times prevent the user from downloading? Also if you click on this rapidly you get an error, specifically a `DefaultErrorHandler`.

At the very least I would like a way to prevent someone from downloading the file more than x times. Preferably it would be nice to also have something like `downloadButton.disableOnClick()` but I can't seem to find a way to re-enable after the download has finished because there are no hooks to notify you when the download is finished but the primary goal is to stop someone from downloading 50x in a row.

Comment: When you disable the button after click?

Comment: The main question is how do you prevent someone from downloading 50x in a row. Ignoring that it's not how do you re-enable the button but when? There are no hooks to let you know when the download is finished.

Comment: Would it be okay to block the download for like 10 seconds and then re-enable it?

Comment: Not really because we do have some people who need to adjust the report settings ever so slightly (change a date) and re-run it. Basically I'm trying to prevent someone from spam clicking the same generated report.

Answer (score 3):

For this:

> but I can't seem to find a way to re-enable after the download has finished because there are no hooks to notify you when the download is finished

No, there are no hooks - not to my knowledge - to get browser's download functionality to tell Vaadin when dowload is ready, from the client side.

However the might be a server side solution.

I believe you create `Resource` from `StreamResource` and in latter implement:

```
@Override
public InputStream getStream() {
    return s;
}
```

Download can be considered to be ready when the stream `s` is closed. But there are no hooks for `InputStream.close()` either. For this you could implement  wrapper implementation for the `InputStream`, like:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CloseNotifyingInputStream extends InputStream  {

    @FunctionalInterface
    public static interface InputStreamCloseListener {
        public void onInputStreamClose(CloseNotifyingInputStream closeNotifyingInputStream);
    }

    private final InputStream wrappedStream;
    private final InputStreamCloseListener closeListener;

    @Override
    public synchronized int read() throws IOException {
        return wrappedStream.read();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException  {
        log.info("Download complete, closing stream");
        closeListener.onInputStreamClose(this);
        wrappedStream.close();          
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Using this kind of a wrapper you could have a notification with a help of a callback function, that then handles any button logic you decide to implement.

Eventually your `s` in `getStream()` would be like:

```
new CloseNotifyingInputStream(getTheActualInputStream(),
            cnis -> log.info("Handling the btn logic")
);
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to disable the button after 50 downloads. I added the button as a parameter to createResource. If it will stay in the same class the parameter is not necessarily needed.

```
int downloaded = 0;
private StreamResource createResource(Button downloadButton) {
    return new StreamResource(new StreamSource() {
        @Override
        public InputStream getStream() {
            downloaded++;
            if (downloaded > 50)
            {
                downloadButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
            .. generate your InputStream
        }
    }, "myImage.png");
}
```

Disclaimer: I am using Vaadin7, but the syntax looks like it did not change.

Comment: That's close to what I'm doing now. The problem is that I used 50 as an example, it would also be nice to prevent people who doubleclick by accident, etc.

Comment: Well the doubleclick you could disable by blocking the button for some time. 1s would fix that. But I assume pirhos solution is better and more like what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Viritin (Vaadin add-on) DownloadButton now supports executing logic when the content has been sent to the client. To show those you'll though need to have Push enabled or add a polling interval to your UI.

See the example code in the project test sources. It uses the disableOnClick feature from Button but then re-enables the button once the content has been written to the browser:

https://github.com/viritin/viritin/blob/master/viritin/src/test/java/org/vaadin/viritin/it/DownloadButtonExample.java